# validate fields in datamapper (CSV to JSON).

Tags: mule, datamapper

Converting from CSV to JSON using mule datamapper. I want to check if required field is empty. If empty log that field and discard it for further processing.

I know in script option we have if(input.data.length >0).'
But how to discard the whole row if this fails??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this within mule datamapper simply by encapsulating the whole conversion within the if statements opening and closing braces. Something like this:

```
if ( input.Quantity > 0 ) {
    output.id = input.id;
    output.Customer = input.Customer;
    output.Quantity = input.Quantity;
    output.Price = input.Price;
}
```

However a different, perhaps better, approach would be to let the datamapper transform every row into JSON and then split and filter as seperate steps in the flow.

```
<flow name="filterindatamapperFlow2" doc:name="filterindatamapperFlow2">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="/tmp/inbox" doc:name="Inbound file"/>
    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="CSV_To_UnfilteredJSON" doc:name="CSV To Unfiltered JSON"/>
    <request-reply>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="splittandprocess" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="result"/>
    </request-reply>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="/tmp/outbox" doc:name="Outbound file"/>
</flow>

<flow name="splittandprocess">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="splittandprocess" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.List" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    <splitter expression="#[payload]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    <message-filter  doc:name="Filter Out Orders With No Quantity" onUnaccepted="handleFilteredMessages">
        <expression-filter expression="#[payload['Quantity'] > 0]" />
    </message-filter>
    <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="false" timeout="1000"/>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="result" exchange-pattern="one-way"/>
</flow>
<flow name="handleFilteredMessages">
    <logger message="Payload filtered #[payload]" level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Scenario is that I have csv file. Checking for a few fields to be non-zero. If one of them is zero, discard the whole row, log that value and proceed to next row in file.

Comment: Exactly and that is what the script above will do. The quantity column on the row is zero that row will be skipped. I will post a more complete example shortly. Also to edit the datamapper script directly switch to the script view instead of the graphical mapper.

Comment: Yes it works, would you know how can I log this value using logger component ?

Comment: Not directly but since mel is executed in the java context you could probably call log4j directly. However in this case I would recommend that you instead transform every line in the datamapper and then use splitter and content based router (choice flow control) to filter out the entries you do not want.

Comment: Extended my answer to show how to filter using a splitter, filter and aggregator instead of filtering within the datamapper.

Comment: I am checking as #[payload.Event !=null] and it is not working as expected.The empty field row is not getting transferred to another flow. I have converted json to object as java.util.List

Comment: Make sure that you have not mixed the two solution suggestions. If you use the second the datamapper script must not contain the if statement.